# Can I specify multiple types for a field in the django model (models.py)?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a approverList which can either be mongo.ListField(mongo.StringField()) or mongo.StringField(). How can I define this in models.py? Thanks

Comment: Why would you ever want to do this? What's wrong with a list with one element?

Comment: It was defined as a string earlier, so I need to maintain backward compatability.

Comment: is it possible to convert the old content? This would be the clean approach. I'd guess otherwise (even if you found a solution) it'll come back and haunt you over and over.